# Auto reset Video recording Android

Tags: android, save, mediarecorder

I am working on a application where I need to record video on a button click of predefined lenth say 15 sec. After 15 sec I want to reset the MediaRecorder automatically without manual intervation My code is here.

```
public void initMediaRecorder(){ 

mRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); 

mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); 
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263); 
mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface()); 
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(15000);
mRecorder.setOutputfile("blahblah On SD card")
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile); 

}
```

Now the recording is getting done but after 15sec my UI is getting freeze and I need to reset manually the recorder. I need to know the event on which I should reset the recorder after 15sec time is done.

Comment: Any clue would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
Maybe this answer will help some one.

Use the following listener

recorder.setOnInfoListener(new medialistener());

```
 class medialistener implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {     
         public void onInfo(MediaRecorder recorder, int what, int extra)
         { 
             if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED)
             {

             }

        // Log.i("video test", "Video Info: "+what+", "+extra);  
         } 
         }
```

cheers.